# Rails Touch and Return attr_accessor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working on a Rails 4 App that creates a key, hashes it on before_create and saves it in a model. If i want to reset this key i can call current_user.touch and before_update will be called and before_update has the same methods as before_create so the old key will be updated with a new one. I want to get that plain text key back on creation so i use attr_accessor and fill a variable with the plain text upon creation and i get back the key which is fine. The problem is, if i call touch, update! i am returned true or false instead of the record so i can't access the attr_accessor variable and if i try to reload it then the key is gone because it was only available in the instance. Does anyone know of a way to force and update and return the record itself in that instance instead of true or false?

```
class Key < ActiveRecord::Base
  include BCrypt

  attr_accessor :access_key_hex
  before_update :set_access_key
  before_create :set_access_key

  def access_key
    @access_key ||= Password.new(access_key_hash)
  end

  belongs_to :user

  protected

  def set_access_key
    self.access_key_hex = SecureRandom.hex(50)
    @access_key = Password.create(access_key_hex)
    self.access_key_hash = @access_key
  end
end
```

In my controller i'm using `@key = active_user.key.update!(nil)`, which works perfectly and it updates the key automatically, the problem is retrieving the key on update, on create its fine.

Comment: Can you post your model code?

Comment: As an FYI, you can probably DRY up your code by utilizing the `after_save` callback, which encompasses both `before_create` and `before_update`.

Comment: @zeantsoi Thanks how would i implement that tho?

Comment: Replace the `before_update` and `before_create` declarations with a single line comprising of: `before_save :set_access_key`.

Comment: What's the status of this question? Are you going to post the complete code? It's a bit pointless to ask a question without providing the requisite details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than running `set_access_key` as an ActiveRecord callback on `touch`, consider declaring the `set_access_key` as a public method and invoking the method on your model instance directly:

```
# app/models/key.rb
class Key < ActiveRecord::Base
    include BCrypt

    attr_accessor :access_key_hex
    # before_update :set_access_key # REMOVE CALLBACK
    # before_create :set_access_key # REMOVE CALLBACK

    def access_key
        @access_key ||= Password.new(access_key_hash)
    end

    belongs_to :user

    def set_access_key
        self.access_key_hex = SecureRandom.hex(50)
        @access_key = Password.create(access_key_hex)
        self.access_key_hash = @access_key
        @access_key # returns access key from the method
    end
end
```

Then, in your controller, all you need to do is invoke the `set_access_key` **directly** on the object instance and the value of the key will be assigned to `@key`:

```
@key = active_user.key.set_access_key
print @key #=> value of the access_key_hex
```

Comment: I'm sorry i didn't mention this earlier but there are two keys instead off one. I just took out the other to make explaining this issue easier.

Comment: What's the point of asking the question if you don't provide the details? It's not any easier for anyone to answer, only to be informed that a critical piece of information has been withheld. Care to update your question?

Comment: Okay, so you have two keys instead of one. Does that change whether this solution works?